# What am I doing wrong with Angular js manual bootstrap process?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.7.2 in a project i'm working on. (I prefer Angular 1.x)

I am doing the bootstrap process manually (because i'm adding scripts programmatically).

But, I am having 2 issues with the manual bootstrap process.

1. I have to use a setTimeout, else the bootstrap never works. And my problem with this is, the more files I add to my project, the longer i have to make the timeout.
2. Sometimes when I load my web page or refresh the site, not all my components are loaded. If i monitor the network traffic, i can sometimes see that the html files are not retrieved at all. And there are no errors in the console or anything.

It seems to me there must be something happening in the **angular.boostrap** process that is failing or getting stuck, but i can't figure it out.

For my first issue, why is the setTimeout required, is there a way to not need this?

Second, why does my site not load sometimes?

Could it be related to the OS locking the files temporarily because of all the source control, anti-virus, other services running on my computer? If so, how can i tell?

I put together a test project with relevant code [here on github](https://github.com/quintonn/AngularBugTest)

I previously thought this was related to the routing, but it's not ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52429544)), But it seems not related to angular-routing after all.

Any information would be much appreciated, this is driving me mad.

**Update 1:**
I have the code running here on [github pages](https://quintonn.github.io/AngularBugTest/).

Best chance to replicate issue is to use google chrome, enter url, open dev tools (f12), then actually load url. Sometimes, the page doesn't load completely.

I have updated the test website to better reflect my project where I add scripts dynamically.

Comment: Have you tried to put your bootstrap code when the document is ready?

Comment: why you add scripts in the body?

Comment: @LuizCarlos I put my bootstrap code inside code like this: (function () {...})(); which only gets executed once document is ready.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I have read that it's better to put script in body. I've tried it in head, makes no difference

Comment: You got a race condition. If you view the log between a page where it works and one where it does not the logs are in a different order. It has to do with when `app.route.js` is resolved. I am not sure why you want to load your scripts like this to begin with. Why not use a gulp script to create a minified/uglified bundle and load everything at once?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs, either when it works or when it doesn't work.
I use visual studio to edit the files and i just preview the in the browser, i don't want to have to run other scripts and processes. This is for dev. When i am done i will bundle and minify for sure though

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution thanks to a comment by [igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260204/igor)

I moved my app.route.js file to be loaded before any of my angular component and directives and from what I can tell this solves my problem.

I will update the linked sample project too